On the inscribed square problem
Will any closed curve contain all four vertices of some square?
It has been proven to be true for piecewise curves.  If so, I just realised that any curve, on a smaller scale, is made of small straight lines. At least, isn't this how a computer would display any digital curve?
Does this mean then, that any curve on a digital screen will contain a square? likewise, can one argue that any drawn curve (like on a paper) will contain a perfect or an almost perfect square? If so, I guess a counterexample to this problem could not be a draw.

The known partial results of the inscribed square problem include the case of piecewise analytic curves, which probably gives a positive answer to anything computer-related. The second question runs into the issue of defining what "any drawn curve (like on a paper)" means in terms of regularity and, since you mentioned it, what an "almost perfect square" is.

Please give at least a reference.
